# JavaScript - replace a list with a list in <li> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help.  I am stuck and very much a beginner to JavaScript & jQuery.

I can find examples all over the web to replace one child element in the DOM.

One example of what I find is at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_replacechild.asp and title is "HTML DOM replaceChild() Method"
That tells me how to replace one.  How do I replace a list of 16 of these?  (Eight pairs).

I've been working on this (off and on) for two weeks (a half hour at a time or more per day) and it is driving me crazy.  It seems like the answer would be so simple.

I need to replace a list with another list.  I think I need to turn it into an array first but not certain.

I know how to obtain the list and turn it into an array with the commands below:

```
//grabs all the inner values as a NodeList

var cardsInnerVal = document.querySelectorAll('li.card i');

//turns each of the inner values into an array

var cardsInnerValArray = Array.from(cardsInnerVal);
```

---

This is the original DOM structure and what I need to replace is the i element

What I have:

```
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></li>
```

There are 16 of these - 8 matching pairs (also a pair of cars , a pair of trains, planes and more...)

---

I know I can replace these one at a time by hard-coding item 1 to replace the existing item 1, but that list will change as soon as I shuffle them again so I have to do it programatically with a loop.

---

I might also be able to do it by using this (below) in some way.  Not sure.

```
//grabs all of the .card class items
var allCards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');  //grabs all the values as a NodeList

var allCardsArray = Array.from(allCards);  //turns each of the card values into an array
```

---

I've tried numerous things that do not work
One attempt at a function - but this is an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: deckField.appendChild is not a function

I think this might not work because it is not in a loop.

```
var deckField = document.querySelector('deck');

// Deal cards to initialize the Game

function deal() {

  for (const item of cardsInnerValArray) {
    $deckField = $('.deck');

    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const icons = item;

    li.classList.add('card');
    li.innerHTML = deckField.appendChild(li);
  }

}

deal();
```

Can anyone make sense of this and help me out?

Comment: What end result are you looking for?

Comment: It's helpful in questions like this to show the html you are starting with and the html you want in the end  with some text and/or code that shows the relationship between the two.

Comment: `.querySelector('deck')` must be `querySelector('.deck')`.

Comment: Such a long post, and still the most relevant information is not in it. Just as the other commenters before me said.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see much jQuery in there. Also, the HTML list you've shown doesn't work so it's hard to figure out what you truly want as an end result.

Do you mean something like this?

```
<ul class="deck">
        <li class="card">card 1</li>
        <li class="card">car 1</li>
        <li class="card">plane 1</li>
        <li class="card">train 1</li>
        <li class="card">card 2</li>
        <!-- etc etc...-->
</ul>
```

If so, something like this via jQuery would work:

```
//Clear the deck. Select it by the class you've given it
//(though it may be safer to give it an id, so you can select
//specifically without worrying about catching any others), then
//clear all the html it contains.

$('.deck').html("");

//use jQuery 'each' to loop over array and put new list items
//into the inner html of the list

$.each(cardsInnerValArray, function(index, value){
    $('.deck').append('<li class="card">' + value + '</li>');
})
```

Updated to add this (according to your comments where you showed me some jQuery 'each' code which wasn't working). I believe the fix below should do the trick.

```
$.each(cardsInnerValArray, function(index, value){
    $('.deck').append('<li class="card"><i class="' + value + '"></i></li>');
});
```

Firstly, you didn't need to break up the HTML string so much. It seems you broke it up into separate little strings for splitting it into `<li>`, `</li>`, and other 'whole' parts. This isn't necessary because HTML is just a mark-up language, it just reads whatever it has been given and attempts to deal with it. You can just put it all in as one big fat string, and only break it up when you need to add variable values, like I've done above with the `+ value +...` part.

Secondly, you attempted to access the desired value with `cardsInnerValArray[value]`. This is incorrect for two reasons. 1: You should be using *index*, so it would be `cardsInnerValArray[index]`. This would work. But it isn't necessary, because... 2: The jQuery 'each' loop provides the value for you already (it's called *value*!).

Here's a brief explanation:

The 'each' method of jQuery loops over the contents of the object you've provided. The 'index' is the index number of the array (starting at 0), and 'value' is the actual value of the content being looked at in the given loop.

So for example, if you have an array like this:

```
["car", "train", "plane", "bus"]
```

Then the jQuery 'each' function will loop like this:

index = 0, value = "car";

index = 1, value = "train";

index = 2, value = "plane";

index = 3, value = "bus";

So in the jQuery 'each' loop, you mainly just need to use the 'value' part to add the data you want. Hence the code I've written above.

Comment: Sorry, the html for the items is below.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Sorry, I thought I included enough of the html to give a good idea of what I am starting with.  Part of the html is below.  I couldn't include all of it.  I got a message saying I was over the limit.

Here is a sample of three of the li elements.  There are 16 in all.  Eight pairs.

    <ul class="deck">
        <li class="card">
            <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="card">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="card match">
            <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
    </ul>

Comment: Thank you Stuart. Yes, that is what the html looks like.  When I try to run it in the Chrome Console it tells me that $('.deck').html("");  is not a function.

Comment: @RickP Have you included jQuery in the project? `$('.deck').html("")` should definitely work. I used versions of that a lot in the work I'm currently doing.

Comment: Thank you Stuart.  I forgot to add jQuery as a src in the html.

Comment: //Getting closer.  I ran the code you first suggested  but the i element within the li element is missing.
// I've tweaked and tried several variations of the code shown below but it adds whatever is in the class=" as its inner text instead of adding it as the class of the i element.
// I now need to put each of the values in the cardsInnerValArray as the class within the i element.

Comment: //running:
$.each(cardsInnerValArray, function(index, value){
    $('.deck').append('<li class="card">' + '<i class=" + cardsInnerValArray[value] + ">' + '</i>' + '</li>');
})
//
// produces <i class=" + cardsInnerValArray[value] + "></i>"
// How can I make the class of i be each of the separate values in the cardsInnerValArray?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to make it not run all of the text together.  It appears in the window fine but then runs everything together.  I've separated lines with two hash marks.

Comment: @RickP I've updated my answer, hopefully it clears things up